# Plugin and Version Conflict with Firebase Messaging

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, plugins, sdk

I have an app that is currently running on the Play Store, built using AndroidStudio, but I want to add the feature of adding notifications to the users. I have been told the best way to do this is through Firebase Messaging.

I added the plugin (version 9.0.0) but this initially caused a conflict issue with the Dart SDK version. I had 2.10 but needed 2.12 So I did the following:

1. Upgraded Flutter - so I was on version 2.12
2. Then started upgrading all plugin version which then caused conflicts because of the 2.12 version
3. I reached the first major conflict because of Flutter_Form_Builder. Even the latest version required Intl plugin to be version 0.16.1 but Firebase Auth required version 0.17.0
4. Tried the hacks here but none worked - https://github.com/danvick/flutter_form_builder/issues/634
5. I then downgraded back to version 2.10
6. Changed back the plugin versions due to the conflict messages
7. Tried installing the earlier version of Firebase Messaging (7.0.2) - but this didn't work as it created a separate major conflict. Firebase Messaging (7.0.2) requires Firebase Core 0.5.1 whereas the Cloud Firestore plugin needs Firebase Core 0.7.0

I'm sure many of you have been here many times before - but this is my first time.

The biggest clash I seem to have is that I can't have both Flutter Form Builder and Firebase Messaging, and will either have to wait for Flutter Form Builder to release a new version or rebuild the entire app away from this plugin (a lot is built around it).

Before I give up on Firebase Messaging I just want to make sure there isn't a different option here I can't see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try if this works? I tested this just earlier. I was able to "flutter pub get" successfully.

```yaml
dependencies:
  # other deps here.
  firebase_core: 0.5.3
  firebase_messaging: 7.0.3
  firebase_auth: 0.18.4+1
  cloud_firestore: 0.14.4
  flutter_form_builder: 4.2.0
  # other deps here.

dependency_overrides:
  intl: "<0.16.0"
```

I'm not sure if there are major API differences between these firebase packages. But you might want to try your luck with these versions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the issue here is firebase_core: 0.5.3 - this clashes with cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0+1 as it needs firebase_core: 0.7.0. If drop cloud_firestore down to 0.13.0+1 it then clashes with something else causing another loop

Comment: Oh wait - I didn't see you had cloud_firestore down to 0.14.4 ........ let me try!

Comment: Genius - this worked!!!!!!!! - Many thanks! .........will confirm this is the answer and award the bounty, but SO says I have to wait a further 15hours, but will do so when I can. Thanks again